# installing ubuntu 12.04 using wi-fi dongle

Tags: 12.04

I keep getting connection problems when trying to install Ubuntu 12.04  as I use a usb network dongle.i have tried all possible solutions given but  i cannot establish a connection to go further on with the installation. is there a way out of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your wifi dongle is not supported by the kernel out of the box. Therefore you have to continue the installation without internet connection and than use the jockey driver program to install the driver for the dongle and than continue to install what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the  firmware for the dongle somewhere in your device in order to install it with a terminal (`Ctrl+Alt+T`) before clicking the install button.

Otherwise you will need a cable connection in order to connect to the network inevitably.